# Copy changes from one subbranch of a branch to subbranch of another branch in Git

Tags: git

Original branch is B. We took a branch A from it and was doing the changes in subbranch X of it. Now I create subbranch Y from B and i need to copy X to Y only. Please confirm if it is possible with Git.

Comment: What is the relationship between branches `X` and `Y`?

Comment: To copy a commit to a different branch you can use `git cherry-pick`, checkout the target branch and issue `git cherry-pick COMMITSHA` to copy a commit onto the branch. Is this what you're after? Be aware that you get what you asked for, a copy of the commit, if you need something else please elaborate.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This sounds like a job for `rebase onto`, but then again we need to know the relation between the two branches to give any answer.

Comment: @tim Both have the code of the same project. As of now, changes were made in X and it needs to be copied to Y.

Comment: No, this isn't clear enough.  Which "changes" are you referring to?  In Git, a change is a commit.  So, which commits from `X` do you want to apply to `Y`?

Comment: Meant the internal code additions and modifications.

Comment: Let me make it clear again. Original branch is B. We took a branch A from it and was doing the changes in subbranch X of it. Now I create subbranch Y from B and i need to copy X to Y.

Comment: Do you mean "copy"? Or do you mean "move"? And again, you *are* talking about commits? Or changes inside the commits?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's difficult to decipher clearly what you're asking, it seems you want to "copy" changes exclusive to X branch (and ignoring the changes in A branch) to Y branch.

```
git rebase --onto X A Y
```

Comment: I don't know, that's what we're still trying to figure out, but at least it is more in line with what he is asking. Be aware that he keeps saying "copy", and rebase will move so I am not entirely sure this is correct either. Though I'm not sure your commit references here are correct". What, specifically, will that rebase onto X?